# Meaning of slash chord without anything left of the slash

Tags: chords, chord-progressions, jazz

In chord charts what does it mean when it says /c#. I know what slash chords are, but what if it doesn't show the first part. An example of what I'm talking about is [here](https://www.learnjazzstandards.com/pdf-viewer/?pdf=St._Thomas_Eb_Instruments).

Comment: Have you ever seen an example where the right side of the slash is a chord (e.g. Em) instead of a single note?

Answer (score 12):

My gut assumption given your example lead sheet is that the empty slash presumes that the base chord to the left of it will still be used. For example, in your example, the "A   /C#" would mean "A   A/C#".

Comment: Your assumption is correct. The chord stays A, but the bass starts a chromatic movement to E

Comment: Spot on. That's really all it could be, but as an ink saving exercise..? +1.

Comment: It could also be a space-saving exercise. I've added chords to pieces that already exist by hand - and tricks like this can allow you to include the full detail you wanted without resorting to tiny unreadable compromises.

Comment: I've also used it to indicate that the bass can move on its own, without resounding the chord above it.